# Flink rocksdb buffers and cache do not work

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb

I have a 3K message/sec system.  A lot of states and windows in the flow.

At the moment my management memory usage is only 84MB although I reserved 15GB for it. On Flink web UI it says 84.4 MB / 14.8 GB.
Rocksdb doesnt use it for cache and buffers. Can you help why?
Below you can see my config.

```
taskmanager.memory.process.size: 51912m
taskmanager.memory.managed.fraction : 0.2
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 360
state.backend: rocksdb
state.backend.rocksdb.localdir: /home/asi/rockdbtmp/datadir
state.backend.rocksdb.thread.num: 4
state.backend.rocksdb.log.dir: /home/asi/flink-1.15.2/log/rocksdb
state.backend.rocksdb.memory.managed: true
state.backend.incremental: true
state.backend.rocksdb.memory.write-buffer-ratio: 0.5
state.backend.rocksdb.memory.high-prio-pool-ratio: 0.1
```

Also, If if use hashmap backend, my system works without any problem but if I change it to rocksdb, it locks in couple of seconds. I think this is also related with this buffer problem.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem was numberOfTaskSlots.
so total managed mem is 27GB and taskSlot is 360.
So a task uses only 27GB/360 memory.  ijust changed it to 36